# How can I format numeric values in RTF/PDF documentation when using templates in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

In process of project management when creating efforts for selected element I set value for *Time* (i.e 2) and Enterprise Architect saves that value with six decimal zeros.
When documenation was generated these values are also exported with six zeros.

Is there a way that I can format those values for zero decimals (i.e 2) and how?

This is RTF Template (other elements are removed).

Value that I wish to format is bolded.

package >
{Pkg.Name}

element >{Element.Name}

effort >
  Time: **{ElemEffort.Value}**

< effort

< element
child package >
< child package
< package

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating RTF documentation, what you can do is use a template fragment.

A template fragment allows you to attach either an SQL query or an EA script, which takes as its input the identity of the current package or element being processed by the document generation engine.

Given that, you can write a snippet of code which retrieves the relevant information and formats it the way you want. Using SQL, you'll need to look at the t_object and t_objecteffort tables; using a script you'll need the Element and Effort classes.

I can't be more specific without the original RTF template.